# O elemento é gerado com um atributo e o respectivo CSS com outro atributo

Tags: angular, angular-material

Criei o componente `toolbar` com o seguinte decorator:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-toolbar',
    templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})
```

Repare que o componente está a utilizar o seletor `app-toolbar`.

Adicionei o seguinte CSS no arquivo `toolbar.component.scss`:

```
app-toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Porém o elemento **não** ficou fixo no topo. Ao inspecionar o elemento no browser, verifiquei que o mesmo recebeu os seguintes atributos:

```
<app-toolbar _ngcontent-c0 _nghost-c1>
    //...
</app-toolbar>
```

Ao verificar o CSS gerado, o mesmo está sendo aplicado ao elemento `app-toolbar` porém com um atributo diferente:

```
app-toolbar[_ngcontent-c1] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

Ou seja, o elemento é renderizado com o atributo `_ngcontent-c0` e o CSS com o atributo `_ngcontent-c1`.

**O que está errado? Por quê o contexto do elemento é diferente do contexto do CSS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comportamento que você está presenciando se deve pelo fato do *framework* Angular utilizar [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom). Resumidamente, o Shadow DOM faz parte do padrão *Web Components* e habilita o encapsulamento da árvore DOM e do estilo DOM. Isso significa que o Shadow DOM permite esconder a lógica DOM atrás de outros elementos. Além disso, permite aplicar estilos que possuem como escopo somente o próprio elemento sem que tais estilos "vazem" para fora de tal elemento.

Angular faz uso do [encapsulamento de *views*](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). Esse conceito é muito importante pois torna possível a criação de componentes que expõem um único elemento customizado com uma lógica DOM escondida por baixo dos panos, e estilos que são aplicados somente para esse elemento.

Para você resolver o seu problema, é necessário utilizar a pseudo-classe [`:host`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host). Da documentação:

> Use the `:host` pseudo-class selector to target styles in the element that hosts the component.
>
> The `:host` selector is the only way to target the host element. You can't reach the host element from inside the component with other selectors because it's not part of the component's own template. The host element is in a parent component's template.

Traduzindo:

> Use a pseudo-classe `: host` para definir estilos no elemento que hospeda o componente.
>
> O seletor `: host` é a única maneira de focar no elemento hospedeiro. Você não pode alcançar o elemento hospedeiro do interior do componente com outros seletores porque não é parte do próprio modelo do componente. O elemento hospedeiro está no modelo de um componente pai.

Dessa maneira, utilizando o seu código como exemplo, dado o componente

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-toolbar',
    templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})
```

O arquivo **toolbar.component.scss** teria o seguinte código para que o elemento do componente seja estilizado corretamente.

```
:host {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Poderia completar a sua resposta com um exemplo utilizando o `:host` e assim ficaria mais completa. Eu sei que basta no meu `scss` declarar a pseudo-classe e dentro dela as classes dos elementos filhos, mas para alguns isso pode não ser muito claro, o exemplo ajudaria.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes seguindo sua sugestão eu complementei a minha resposta.